# Как сделать смену темы на ajax?

Tags: ajax

нужно сделать возможность смены темы сайта на ajax, то есть в head к примеру прописано

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/'.$user['them'].'.css" type="text/css"/>
```

И что бы при клике на кнопку
Светлая тема
Темная тема
Менялся css без перезагрузки страницы и собственно обновлялась запись в бд, что бы каждый пользователь к примеру мог менять тему со светлой на темную и наоборот, не знаю как такое сделать без перезагрузки, если кто знает не отказался бы от примера, заранее спасибки)